# Angular.js html5mode(true) and normal anchor href links?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angularjs, hyperlink

Okay so the problem is this:

I want to have an URL like this http://www.domain.com/bla not http://www.domain.com/#/bla

And I solved that using html5mode(true). Great for me!

But now when user goes to //www.domain.com/bla (for example by typing it directly in address bar) he will be shown nothing because angular just rewrites url upon loading the # url. So actually //www.domain.com/bla doesn't exist as url.

My question is, how can I show page //www.domain.com/#/bla when user enters //www.domain.com/bla ?(this has to be done from the back-end, in my case node.js)

I think this has something to do with it //github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

But this is ui-router, I would like to avoid it.

Comment: Are you using UI.router?

Comment: I am using angular router.

Comment: Could you post the code you're using? HTML and angular.

Answer (score 0):

Use in html head tag base
Href set your base URL

```
<head>

  <base href="/set your base url">
</head>
```

If you're running your angular app on an apache server you can easily add this rule in an .htaccess file.

```
# Apache .htaccess

# angularjs pushstate (history) support:
# See http://www.josscrowcroft.com/2012/code/htaccess-for-html5-history-pushstate-url-routing/
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(css¦js|html|png) #Add extra extensions needed.
    RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
</ifModule>
```

if node js express use this
app js

```
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');`
```

your node js

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();

//initialize static server that will spit out contents of public folder
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.listen(9823); //the express server will start on port 9823
console.log('started');
```

Comment: I am using nodejs for backend. As for base tag in head, I am using the same head for all the pages. What should I exactly put in href attribute. www.domain.com or the /url-of-this-particular-page

Comment: set un base tag href='/domain' and try

Comment: it doesn't work for <base href="/register"/>. I am hosting it on http://localhost:3000/ and the page that I want is on /register

Comment: set this <base href='/localhost:3000'> and try

Comment: I am not sure if you got it. I want to get to domain.com/#/something when I enter domain.com/something in the browser

Comment: No luck with that either :(

Comment: if you set this tag not wrked?

Comment: If I set <base href="/localhost:3000'> It's still the same. As if I didn't tocuh anything

Comment: you used node js express?

Comment: Yes, I use nodejs express.

Comment: Okay this is the latest breakthrough. I am obviously doing something wrong with express/angular.js routing because I am intercepting /register with nodejs and serving that page directly. How can I configure express to redirect /register to /#/register?

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know how to answer your question without an idea about what your code looks like. However, I can post an example of what works for what you want. I would, on the other hand, use Angular's UI-Router instead of ngRouter. I find that it is a lot easier to work with. For what you want, it is fairly easy to do in `ui.router`.

HTML:

```
 <body ng-app="someApp">
   <nav class="whatever"> 
    <ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
      <li><a ui-sref='new_page'>Whatever</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
   <div ui-view></div>  
 </body>
```

Angular:

```
var someApp = angular.module('SomeApp', ['ui.router']);

someApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', function($stateProvider, $locationProvider)  {
 $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

$stateProvider.state('landing', {
  url: '/',
  controller: 'Landing',
  templateUrl: '/templates/landing.html'
 });

$stateProvider.state('new_page', {
  url: '/',
  controller: 'NewPage',
  templateUrl: '/templates/new_page.html'
 });
}]);
```

Of course, you don't need separate controllers, but I am providing one here for you. I pulled this example code from a project that I recently completed, so I know that it works. You will be able to access your pages using `localhost/#/` and `localhost/landing`, for example.